# differential equation to power to power series

Tags: algebra-precalculus, power-series, vector-analysis, formal-power-series

What is the power series, (or summation form) for the following equation?
I know the first couple of terms, but am unable to write it as a power series.
The equation is dy/dx +x*y = x^2 There is also the condition y(0)=0

So far I have managed to work out that the third term is 1/3 the fifth term is -1/15 and so on. The other terms are all 0.

Comment: the equation is dy/dx +xy =x^2

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You should edit the equation into the question itself. You should also add some of your effort so far, or else the question is likely to get closed. Also, what is a "power series for an equation"? You need to clarify.

Comment: Do you mean the Maclaurin series of the solution with initial condition $y(0)=0$?

Comment: yes that's what I mean

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{dy}{dx}+xy=x^2$.
Let $g=e^{x^2/2}$ then $g(0)=1$, $g'(0)=0$.

$\frac{d}{dx}(g y)=x^2g$ by integrating factor.

$g'y+gy'=x^2g \implies  y'(0)=0.$

By Frobenius' Method.

$xy=\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_kx^{p+k+1}$

$y'=\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_k(p+k)x^{p+k-1}=c_0px^{p-1}+c_1(p+1)x^p+\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_{k+2}(p+k+2)x^{p+k+1}$

So:

$y'+xy=c_0px^{p-1}+c_1(p+1)x^p+\sum_{k=0}^\infty [c_{k+2}(p+k+2)+c_k]x^{p+k+1}=x^2$

So we need $\frac{c_{k+2}}{c_k}=\frac{-1}{(p+k+2)}$

$c_0px^{p-3}+c_1(p+1)x^{p-2}+\sum_{k=0}^\infty [c_{k+2}(p+k+2)+c_k]x^{p+k-1}=1$

Suppose $c_0=0$. If we only allow non-negative powers of $x$, then $p=2$ and $c_1=1/3$.

If $c_1=0$ then $p=3$ and $c_0=1/3$. In either case, the iterative process above generates the other coefficients defining the function.

Case $c_1=0$: $c_0=1/3, c_2=-1/15,c_4=1/105,...$

Case $c_0=0$: $c_1=1/3, c_3=-1/15, c_5=1/105, ...$